# There is a link to the comment under the post from Vkontakte. How to get the content of a comment from a link

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I tried using beautifulsoup, but when parsing the page for some reason gives the mobile version, where links to comments have a different look. Using vk_api, I need to specify the group id, which I need. I will be happy to give you any advice! Thanks! Here is the link ["link"](https://vk.com/wall-12648877_5011889?reply=5011893). If you click on it, the comment "sexism" will appear. I want to implement this programmatically in python. If you can help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there your code/URL/desired output?

Comment: Edited at your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to extract word "sexism" from the provided link that includes `reply=<some number>`.

You can do this for example:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://vk.com/wall-12648877_5011889?reply=5011893'
reply_number = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query)['reply'][0]

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
text = soup.select_one('div.ReplyItem:has(a[name="reply{}"]) .ReplyItem__body'.format(reply_number)).text.strip()
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
sexism
```

---

EDIT:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://vk.com/wall-12648877_5013166?reply=5013335&thread=5013176'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
reply_number = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query)['reply'][0]

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

text = soup.select_one('div.ReplyItem:has(a[name="reply{reply_number}"]) .ReplyItem__body, .reply_text div[id$="_{reply_number}"]'.format(reply_number=reply_number)).text.strip()
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
ахаха, опять ты. и опять твою фотку запостили в комментах, просто ОР, в прошлый раз ты что-то про геев говорил кажется. ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. You understand me correctly. The only thing that comes out is an error on the penultimate line "AttributeError: the 'nonetype' object does not have the 'text'attribute  "

Comment: @ИванПетров Can you share URL which produces this error?

Comment: this url is - https://vk.com/wall-12648877_5013166?reply=5013335&thread=5013176